# Parsear Json a Java Collection List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, json, jackson

He serializado un objeto usando Jackson ObjectMapper,

```
// Inicialización y configuración del mapper Jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());// Moódulo para que Jackson entienda los tipos de dato de Hibernate5
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);// No incluye en la serialización del Objeto a Json los datos nulos o vacios

String jsonFileString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

una vez obtenido el String **jsonFileString**, quiero que todos los valores del json "x": "y" se parseen a un Map y si encuentra en el String un array []  que lo convierta en una lista.

He probado con el readValue del ObjecMapper

```
Map<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonFileString, HashMap.class);
```

esto funciona pero cuando encuentra un array en jsonFileString lo transforma en un String, lo que me gustaría conseguir es que al encontrar un array lo convirtiera en una List y siga parseando las propiedades de cada objeto que encuentre, de modo que tendria que parsearlo a `List<Map<String, Object>`

¿Alguna idea de si existe alguna configuración para conseguir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la linea que necesitarias para esa configuracion

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true);
```

Esta sacada de : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial , en el punto 4.4 Handling Collections